# loading data to Azure DW using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, etl, azure-data-factory

I am populating azure data warehouse with ADF and I need to prepare an incremental insert/update operation. My source can contain data that is already loaded to DW so I need to perform a check if data is loaded and perform an operation. Basically the idea is to fetch data everyday for past 7 days in case someone did update historical data.

At first I tried using copy activity with custom query on source and then on destination using stored procedure that will check by business key if record already exists or not and perform insert or update. But I cannot find how to process results of source query row per row and pass it to SP.

What would be best approach that will fit my case? Basically I am looking for SSIS inside azure cloud

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to land the loaded data into something like SQL DB first (if you aren't already). Then use a stored procedure on that to produce the merge style behaviour and deal with the 7 day window. Eg:

```
{
"name": "SprocActivitySamplePipeline",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
    {
    "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
    "typeProperties": {
        "storedProcedureName": "sp_sample",
        "storedProcedureParameters": {
            "DateTime": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', SliceStart)"
        }
    }
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-stored-proc-activity

In this case the ADF input and output datasets can be relational tables in the database.

ADF is not SSIS, sadly. But if you want to compare it think of it more like the SSIS control flow, rather than the data flow and ETL engine.

You'll therefore need a chain of activities to do what you require. In your screen shot above you have SQL DB already as the source so I'm a little confused as to what the actually problem is.

Maybe run the proc over the data in SQL DB first to a staged area. Then to the copy to SQL DW.

Hope this helps.